# Plotting linear regression with Date/Week on x axis using Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, regression, seaborn

### Data

my company uses some weird date notation, which has this format: *[2 digits week number][2 digit working hours]*. Both groups use leading zeros. So the data could like: 0801, 0802, 0901, 0902, 0903, 1001, 1002, 1003

For each of this "dates" there is a scoring. This is just regular floating numbers from 0 to 100.

**Example (csv):**

```
wxxhxx,scoring
0101,5.3
0102,6.6
0103,6.2
```

[Here is some sample data](https://pastebin.com/Sn2CM5n9)

### Example

**With this data** I want to **create a scatter plot** including a **linear regression**!

I was able to create this regression using Seaborn (which uses matplotlib). Yet some binning is happening here:

[image: Linear Regression]

The code I’m using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
sns.regplot('wxxhxx', 'scoring', df)
plt.show()
```

When using Seaborn’s strip plot the data looks "nicer", yet there is no regression here:
[image]

Using:

```
sns.stripplot(x='wxxhxx', y='scoring', data=df)
```

### My Problem

Is there any way to combine the looks of these two methos (regplot and stripplot). I would like to have a **regression within the strip plot**, OR I would like the to get a **equidistant distribution** (like in strip plot) **of the x values within the regplot**, so that the values don’t stack.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: This looks like there are bins for the regplot, although it should normally not use them by default. But you could try to add "bins=1000" or something like this to your regplot and see what happens.

Comment: The reason is that `stripplot` is plotting categorical data on the x axis, whereas `regplot` requires numerical data and so looks like the x axis is grouped

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. I also tried to force regplot to use strings but this results in an error.

Comment: @NilsSchlüter I already tried bins but there is no much effect. Best effect has x_jitter but this ruins the scale of my x-axis...

Comment: A regression line through categorical data seems completely unreasonable. There is no use for such line whatsoever because it is completely arbitrarily placed through categories. From that we can draw the conclusion that the simplest option you have is to just plot a line in your plot whereever you want it to be, `plt.plot()` makes line plotting very easy.

Comment: Did you read the text at all? In short. I’ve got some time on my x-axis and a scoring (float) on my y-axis. Technically, I’m not in categorical scope, yet due to the weird date format I kinda look for a workaround. And by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression

Comment: [Here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fabianp/minirank/blob/master/notebooks/comparison_ordinal_logistic.ipynb) would be a python implementation for ordinal regression. I somehow doubt that this is what you're after though. From how the question reads you want a meaningless line in the data.