# Plotting ordinal regression using Seaborn (Python)

Tags: python, linear-regression, seaborn

I’ve got some data set ([look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175861/plotting-linear-regression-with-date-week-on-x-axis-using-seaborn)) **containing ordinal data** (actually it’s a weird time format, but it’s fine to treat it ordinal) and **I want to create a scatter plot along with a linear regression line**.

Since it is possible in Stats to do so ([see some wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression)), the question is; is there any way Seaborn can do this? Or are there any alternatives in the Python world?

Comment: Repeating my comment on [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175861/plotting-linear-regression-with-date-week-on-x-axis-using-seaborn): A regression line through categorical data seems completely unreasonable. There is no use for such line whatsoever because it is completely arbitrarily placed through categories. From that we can draw the conclusion that the simplest option you have is to just plot a line in your plot whereever you want it to be, plt.plot() makes line plotting very easy.

Comment: Categorical ≠ Ordinal. Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data#Regression_applications and here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression ...

Comment: Ok, suppose you want to really do ordinal regression. First of all it's clear that seaborn cannot do it. So, what would be the model to fit? Or are you asking about finding a good model? But then how would that relate to plotting? In the latter case, your question would be better off at another site about statistics, not SO. Once you can provide a model one can help here with implementing it into code. Still as said, I have the impression this is all about plotting some arbitrary line into the plot which is close to the points in screen coordinates?